# Spring boot schema-based multitenant is always pointing to default schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement a schema-based multitenant to my spring boot application, but the connection is always pointing to the default ("public") schema.

these are the files I added to achieve the multitenant approach:

TenantContext:

```
public class TenantContext {
  private static final ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

  public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenantId) {
    currentTenant.set(tenantId);
  }

  public static String getCurrentTenant() {
    return currentTenant.get();
  }

  public static void clear() {
    currentTenant.remove();
  }
}
```

ConectionProvider

```
@Component
public class MultiTenantSchemaConnectionProvider
    implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

  private final DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  public MultiTenantSchemaConnectionProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  @Override
  public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
  }

  @Override
  public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    connection.close();
  }

  @Override
  public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
    final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
    connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
    return connection;
  }

  @Override
  public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection)
      throws SQLException {
    connection.setSchema(CurrentTenantResolver.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
    releaseAnyConnection(connection);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
    hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, this);
  }
}
```

TenantResolver:

```
@Component
public class CurrentTenantResolver
    implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

  public static final String DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "public";

  @Override
  public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
    return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant() != null
        ? TenantContext.getCurrentTenant()
        : DEFAULT_SCHEMA;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
    hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, this);
  }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object)
      throws Exception {
    String tenantID = request.getHeader("X-TENANT-ID");
    if (tenantID == null) {
      response.setStatus(400);
      return false;
    }
    TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenantID);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void postHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response,
      Object handler,
      ModelAndView modelAndView)
      throws Exception {
    TenantContext.clear();
  }
}
```

InterceptorConfig:

```
@Component
public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor);
    }
}
```

is there something I'm missing?

I have the "users" entity in the default schema and the tenant1 schema. When I send a request wit the header **X-TENANT-ID=tenant1** I got the users from the default schema